# User being added to 1 role only (asp.net membership)

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, roles, membership, createuserwizard

I am trying to allow a user to select a role on createuserwizard from a dropdownlist containing all roles. I dont get  errors but  user always added to the "Offering Rooms" role no matter what dropdownlist item is selected.

Code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        roleDropDownList = RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("RoleDropDownList")
        roleDropDownList.DataSource = Roles.GetAllRoles()
        roleDropDownList.DataBind()
    End Sub

    Protected Sub RegisterUser_CreatedUser(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles RegisterUser.CreatedUser         
        Roles.AddUserToRole(RegisterUser.UserName, roleDropDownList.SelectedValue)         
    End Sub
```

Markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="RoleDropDownList" runat="server">

                                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Html:

```
<option value="Offering Rooms">Offering Rooms</option>
<option value="Seeking Rooms">Seeking Rooms</option>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add check if this is post back and not bind again:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
     If Not IsPostBack Then        
        roleDropDownList = RegisterUser.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("RoleDropDownList")
        roleDropDownList.DataSource = Roles.GetAllRoles()
        roleDropDownList.DataBind()
     End If
End Sub
```